# Three complex and Euler characteristic zero

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

So this is an excerpt from Thurston's three manifolds text. He goes onto state that by constructing a complex by gluing faces of polyhedra we have the following condition. Such a complex is a manifold iff it has Euler characteristic zero. Now it is not readily apparent to me why such a thing is true. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions why this is true?

Comment: If the complex is a manifold, the Euler characteristic is zero by Poincaré duality. I don't know about the other direction.

Comment: But $\chi(S^2) = 2$...?! And you can obtain $S^2$ as a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi - yes, but the OP indicated in the title that this is about $3$-dimensional complexes. $S^2$ is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: @JackLee ah that's what the "three" is all about...